# Facebook messenger template list not working on messenger app

Tags: php, facebook-messenger-bot

Please I need some help......am developing a Facebook messenger chatbot and I have issue with the List template. When I send the template, the response is received and displays well on the web but on the messenger app, everything gets lumped in one button. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
   if($message == "about"){
    $answer = ["attachment"=>[
     "type"=>"template",
     "payload"=>[
       "template_type"=>"list",
       "elements"=>[
         [
            "title"=> "Founder",
                   "image_url"=> "https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/Migrating-Your-Symfony-Website.jpg",
                   "subtitle"=> "Frederick Angel",
                   "default_action"=> [
                        "type"=> "web_url",
                         "url"=> "https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-symfony-from-cpanel-to-cloud-hosting/",
                         "webview_height_ratio"=> "tall",
                        // "messenger_extensions"=> true
                        // "fallback_url"=> "https://peterssendreceiveapp.ngrok.io/"
                    ],
           "buttons"=>[
             [
               "type"=>"postback",
               "title"=>"Read about him",
               "payload"=>"Frederick Angel",
               "webview_height_ratio"=> "tall",
              //  "messenger_extensions"=>true
             ],
           ]
         ],
           [
           "title"=>"Concepts?",
           "default_action"=> [
                "type"=> "web_url",
                "url"=> "https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-symfony-from-cpanel-to-cloud-hosting/",
                "webview_height_ratio"=> "tall",
                // "messenger_extensions"=> true
                // "fallback_url"=> "https://peterssendreceiveapp.ngrok.io/"
            ],
           "buttons"=>[
             [
               "type"=>"postback",
               "title"=>"Read about it",
               "payload"=>"concepts",
               "webview_height_ratio"=> "tall"
             ],
           ]
         ]
     ]
   ]];
 $template = [
   'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
   'message' => $answer
];
  }
```

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: Showing some code will help

Comment: Just added some code